# Android Shared Preferences prevent overwriting while storing object

Tags: java, android, arrays, sharedpreferences, androidx

I have am using shared preferences to store a string to a calendar day. I have a class which adds a decorator and saves a string to a selected day (string from user input), and it works fine. My trouble arises when I try to add a new date, the shared preferences is being over written (which is expected).

Method for saving the string to calendar day

```
        final CalendarDay day1 = date;
                final ArrayList<CalendarDay> selectedEventDay = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                    selectedEventDay.add(day1);
            }
             String editedText = noteEditText.getText().toString();
                            CustomEventDay customEventDay = new CustomEventDay(editedText, selectedEventDay);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            String json = gson.toJson(customEventDay);
                            prefsEditor.putString("CustomEventCal", json);
                            prefsEditor.apply();
```

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to use this same method to save new data for a new date. Currently if a user selects another date, the current date stored in shared preferences and it's string & associated day is over written with the new date data.

Comment: You'd need to specify unique preference key for each day, but doing so is discouraged. For any complex data You should look into setting up some kind of database.

Comment: You can add more date with different key. For a small number of date, this method is okay but if you want to use for large number of data, it is better to use sqlite database. Sqlite will give a more convenient way to store and retrieve data.

Comment: Okay I will look into storing the data in SQLite. I'm assuming it's also possible to store in SQLite with the same gson.Json method I am using here?

Comment: Yes, you can use Gson with sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the recommended way in the comments using SQlite is good, sometimes you only need a small number of data and then it is easier to work with Shared Preferences:

So if the number of events will remain small you can start using an array of objects and then use Gson again:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<CustomEventDay> events = // initialized with the content of your shared preferences
events.add(customEventDay);
String json = gson.toJson(events);
```